# Im unable to import specific class in Python 3.7.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, class, import

Hello I'm having issues with 'import' in python 3.7.3. I've tried to import a module from a specific folder to another module in another specific folder, both folders share the same hierarchy level. When I run 'python3 main.py' I get an error message.

I don't understand what's wrong. I'd like to meet the best fix available, in order to help the maintenance of the project. Any help will be appreciated!

PYTHONPATH value:

```
/home/gabriel/bot/twee-crawler/src
```

Project structure:

```
.
├── clear
├── connect
├── data_bolso_lulahaddad.txt
├── Document.docx
├── dump
├── install
├── requirements.txt
├── root
├── run
└── src
    ├── config.json
    ├── data
    │   ├── accounts.csv
    │   ├── medias.csv
    │   ├── medias-profiles.csv
    │   ├── output.csv
    │   └── profiles.csv
    ├── database
    │   ├── db.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── __pycache__
    │       ├── db.cpython-37.pyc
    │       └── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
    ├── graph
    │   ├── graph.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── __pycache__
    │       ├── graph.cpython-37.pyc
    │       └── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
    ├── main.py
    ├── output
    │   ├── data.json
    │   ├── graph.gexf
    │   ├── media-profiles.csv
    │   └── retweeted_authors.txt
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── db.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── db.cpython-35.pyc
    │   ├── db.cpython-37.pyc
    │   ├── graph.cpython-35.pyc
    │   ├── graph.cpython-37.pyc
    │   ├── report.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── report.cpython-35.pyc
    │   ├── report.cpython-37.pyc
    │   ├── settings.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── settings.cpython-35.pyc
    │   ├── settings.cpython-37.pyc
    │   ├── twittery.cpython-35.pyc
    │   └── twittery.cpython-37.pyc
    ├── report
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
    │   │   └── report.cpython-37.pyc
    │   └── report.py
    ├── settings
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
    │   │   └── settings.cpython-37.pyc
    │   └── settings.py
    ├── test
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── test.py
    └── twittery
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── __pycache__
        │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
        │   └── twittery.cpython-37.pyc
        └── twittery.py
```

db.py code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from pymongo import MongoClient
from settings import settings
import json
import pdb
import numpy as np
import datetime
from graph import graph
import os
import bson
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

# import subprocess

class MongoAccess(object):
    host = 'localhost'
    port = 27017
    database = 'twitter'
    client = MongoClient(host, port)

    def __init__(self):
        print("Creating database indexes to search quickly...")
        c = self.client[self.database].list_collections()
        for i in c:
            collection = str(i["name"])
            self.client[self.database][collection].create_index([("id", -1)])

    def db_name(self):
        return self.database

    def export_collection(self, db, collection):
        # subprocess.call(['../export.sh'])
        os.system("mongodump  --db " + db + " --collection " + collection)

    def import_collection(self, db, collectionTarget, collectionOrigin):
        # subprocess.call(['../import.sh'])
        os.system(
            "mongorestore --collection " + collectionTarget + " --db " + db + " ./dump/" + db + "/" + collectionOrigin + ".bson")

    def export_all_tweets(self):
        c = self.client[self.database].list_collections()
        for i in c:
            if (str(i["name"]).find("tweets") > -1):
                collection = str(i["name"])
                print(collection)
                self.export_collection(self.database, collection)

    def export_all_profiles(self):
        c = self.client[self.database].list_collections()
        for i in c:
            if (str(i["name"]).find("followers") > -1):
                collection = str(i["name"])
                print(collection)
                self.export_collection(self.database, collection)

    def import_all_followers(self):
        c = settings.medias_accounts_toSearch
        for i in c[0]:
            # pdb.set_trace()
            collection = str(i) + "_followers"
            print(collection)
            self.import_collection(self.database, collection, collection)

    def import_all_followers_profiles(self):
        c = settings.accounts_toSearch
        ind = 0
        for i in c[1]:
            # pdb.set_trace()
            collection = str(c[0][ind]) + "_followers"
            print(collection)
            self.import_collection(self.database, collection, collection)
            ind += 1

    def import_all_tweets(self):
        c = settings.urls_toSearch
        for i in c[0]:
            # pdb.set_trace()
            collection = "tweets_" + str(i.replace(" ", "_"))
            print(collection)
            self.import_collection(self.database, collection, collection)

    def drop_collections(self):
        c = self.client[self.database].list_collections()
        for i in c:
            collection = str(i["name"])
            print(collection)
            self.client[self.database][collection].drop()

    def insert_one(self, data, collection):
        if self.client[self.database][collection].find_one({"id": data["id"]}) == None:
            print("Saving new ID [" + str(data["id"]) + "] in collection [" + str(collection) + "]")
            return self.client[self.database][collection].insert_one(data)
        else:
            print("This ID is already collected")

    def date_to_dictionary(self, date):
        date = self.convert_to_datetime(date)
        return dict({"day": int(date.split("-")[2]), "month":int(date.split("-")[1]), "year": int(date.split("-")[0])})

    def delete_one(self, data, collection):
        if self.client[self.database][collection].find_one({"id": data["id"]}) != None:
            print("Deleting id [" + data["id"] + "] in collection [" + collection + "]")
            return self.client[self.database][collection].delete_one(data)
        else:
            print("ID not present in collection \n")

    def get_followers(self, collection):
        # print(dir(self.client[self.database].list_collections()))
        c = self.client[self.database].list_collections()
        for i in c:
            if ((str(i["name"]).find("followers") > -1) and (str(i["name"]) == collection)):
                return [e["id"] for e in self.client[self.database][i["name"]].find({})]
                # print((e["id"]))
                # pass

    def filter1(self):
        collection = "LulaHaddad_followers"
        forbArr = self.get_followers("jairbolsonaro_followers")
        query = {"id": {"$nin": forbArr[:100]}}
        # print(forbArr)
        ffile = open('data_bolso_lulahaddad.txt', 'w')
        result = self.skiplimit(collection, query, 5000, 1)
        for i in result:
            print(i)
        print(len(result))

    def clear_collection_name(self, collection):
        cleared_name = collection.replace("'", "").replace(",", "").replace("tweets_", "").replace("_", " ")
        return cleared_name

    def is_tweet_collection(self, collection):
        if (collection.replace("'", "").replace(",", "").split("_")[0] == "tweets"):
            return True
        return False

    def find_time_interval(self):

        collections = []
        date_list = []
        collections = self.get_collections_name_list(collections)

        for collection in collections:
            if (collection.split("_", 1)[0] == 'tweets'):
                print("Colecao:" + str(collection))
                cursor = self.client[self.database][collection].find({"created_at": {"$exists": "true"}})
                for document in cursor:
                    date_list.append(self.convert_to_datetime(document['created_at']))
        date_list.sort()
        oldest = 0
        latest = len(date_list) - 1
        return [date_list[oldest], date_list[latest]]

    def find(self, key, list):
        list.append(key)
        index = 0
        while (key['id'] != list[index]['id']):
            index += 1
        if index == len(list) - 1:
            list.remove(key)
            return False
        list.remove(key)
        return True

    def format_datetime(self, datetime):
        return datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    def convert_to_datetime(self, string):
        return self.format_datetime(datetime.datetime.strptime(str(string).split(" ")[0], '%Y-%m-%d'))

    def is_on_date_interval(self, datetime, since, until):
        datetime_object = self.convert_to_datetime(datetime)
        if(datetime_object >= self.convert_to_datetime(since) and datetime_object <= self.convert_to_datetime(until)):
            return True
        return False

    def find_intersection(self, collection, collectionCompare, since, until):

        since_date = self.date_to_dictionary(since)
        until_date = self.date_to_dictionary(until)

        print("STATUS: Finding intersection " + collection + " and " + collectionCompare)

        """ Algoritmo responsavel por extrair a interseccao entre duas collections. """
        result = self.client[self.database][collection].aggregate_raw_batches([{
            "$lookup": {
                "from": collectionCompare,
                "localField": "id",
                "foreignField": "id",
                "as": "result",
            }
        },
            {
                "$match": {
                    "$or": [
                        {"created_at":
                             {"$gte": datetime.datetime(since_date['year'], since_date['month'], since_date['day']),
                              "$lte": datetime.datetime(until_date['year'], until_date['month'], until_date['day'])}
                         }, {"id": {'$exists': 'true'}}
                    ],
                    "result": {"$ne": []}
                }
            },
            {
                "$project": {
                    "_id": 0,
                    "result": 0
                }
            }
        ])
        #print("Intersection found.")

        it = []
        for itr in result:
            it = bson.decode_all(itr)
            # print(len(it))
        return it

    def write_to_JSON(self, data, name):
        "Algoritmo que escreve um arquivo JSON a partir de um JSON criado"
        with open('output/' + name + '.json', 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(data, outfile)

    def count_single_collection(self, collection, since, until):

        since_date = self.date_to_dictionary(since)
        until_date = self.date_to_dictionary(until)

        return self.client[self.database][collection].count({"$or": [{"created_at":
                             {"$gte": datetime.datetime(since_date['year'], since_date['month'], since_date['day']),
                              "$lte": datetime.datetime(until_date['year'], until_date['month'], since_date['day'])}
                         }, {"id": {'$exists': 'true'}}
                    ]})

    def calculate_intersection_union(self, since, until):
        "Algoritmo que calcula a interseccao e uniao de todos os conjuntos e os escreve em um JSON"
        resultJSON = []
        collections = []

        self.get_collections_name_list(collections)

        num_elementos_lista = len(collections)
        iteml = 0
        itemc = 1

        while (iteml < num_elementos_lista):
            while (itemc < num_elementos_lista):
                if(self.is_tweet_collection(collections[iteml]) and self.is_tweet_collection(collections[itemc])):
                    intersection = len(self.find_intersection(collections[iteml], collections[itemc], since, until))
                    resultJSON.append({
                        'coll1': collections[itemc],
                        'coll2': collections[iteml],
                        'interseccao': intersection,
                        'uniao': self.count_single_collection(collections[iteml], since, until) +
                                 self.count_single_collection(collections[itemc], since, until) -
                                 intersection
                    })
                itemc += 1
            iteml += 1
            itemc = iteml + 1

        self.write_to_JSON(resultJSON, 'data')

    def processCollections(self):
        """ Algoritmo que faz o cruzamento das collections para fazer o calculo da interseccao em seguida. """
        print("Combinating collections to have the size of each intersection.")
        collections = []
        wasteArr = []
        resultJSON = []

        self.get_collections_name_list(collections)
        wArray = tuple(collections)

        for i in wArray:
            wasteArr.append(i['name'])
            for k in wArray:
                try:
                    if (wasteArr.index(k['name']) < 0):
                        pass

                except ValueError:
                    if (("_followers" in i['name']) and ("_followers" in k['name'])):
                        if (i['name'] != k['name']):
                            print(i['name'], k['name'])
                            resultJSON.append({
                                "coll1": i['name'].replace("_followers", ""),
                                "coll2": k['name'].replace("_followers", ""),
                                # "ids": self.findIntersection(i['name'], k['name']),
                                "qtd": len(self.findIntersection(i['name'], k['name']))
                            })
        return resultJSON

    def skiplimit(self, collection, query, page_size, page_num):
        """returns a set of documents belonging to page number `page_num`
        where size of each page is `page_size`.
        """
        # Calculate number of documents to skip
        skips = page_size * (page_num - 1)
        # Skip and limit
        cursor = list(self.client[self.database][collection].find(query).skip(skips).limit(page_size))
        # arr = [x for x in cursor]
        # Return documents
        return cursor

    def count_all_collections(self, collections, type):
        c = self.client[self.database].list_collections()
        result = []
        labels = []
        for i in c:
            if(type == "followers"):
                if((str(i["name"]).find("followers") > -1) and (str(i["name"]) in collections)):
                    label = str(i["name"]).split("_")[0]
                    labels.append(label)
                    result.append(self.client[self.database][i["name"]].count())

            if(type == "tweets"):
                if(str(i["name"]).find("tweets") > -1):
                    label = str(i["name"]).split("tweets_")[1]
                    labels.append(label)
                    result.append(self.client[self.database][i["name"]].count())

        return [result, labels]

    def get_collection_list(self):
        collectionsName = self.client[self.database].list_collections()
        return collectionsName

    def get_collections_name_list(self, list):
        """Algoritmo que retorna uma lista com o nome de todas as colecoes"""
        collections_list = self.get_collection_list()

        for collection in collections_list:
            list.append(collection['name'])

        return list
```

twittery.py code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# from tweepy.parsers import JSONParser
from settings import settings
from database import db
import math
import numpy as np
import os
import pdb
import time
import tweepy

# import json
# import pandas as

db = db.MongoAccess()

settings.init()
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(settings.consumer_key, settings.consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(settings.access_token, settings.access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
# api = tweepy.API(auth, parser=JSONParser())

def get_user_id(account):
    return api.get_user(screen_name = account)

def clear(array):
    return list(dict.fromkeys(array))

def write_txt_output(path, filename, output):
    file_output = open(path + filename + '.txt', 'w')
    file_output.write(
        "Autores retweetados pelas contas: " + str(output[0]) + "\nAutores dos retweets dos retweetados: " + str(
            output[1]))
    file_output.close()

def is_retweet(tweet):
    if hasattr(tweet, 'retweeted_status'):
        return True
    return False

def append_retweet(tweet, list):
    if is_retweet(tweet):
        list.append(tweet.retweeted_status.author.screen_name)

def get_retweeted_authors(account, nposts):
    retweeted_authors = []
    user = api.get_user(account)
    cursor = tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, id=user.id, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

    for tweet in cursor.items(nposts):
        append_retweet(tweet, retweeted_authors)

    return retweeted_authors

def track_accounts(nposts):
    print('\nSTATUS: Finding retweeted authors')
    retweeted_authors = []
    retweeted_authors_retweets = []

    for account in settings.accounts_toTrack:
        print('STATUS: Collecting authors retweeted by ' + account)
        retweeted_authors = get_retweeted_authors(account, nposts)

    for author in retweeted_authors:
        print('STATUS: Collecting authors retweeted by ' + author)
        retweeted_authors_retweets = get_retweeted_authors(author, nposts)

    results = (clear(retweeted_authors), clear(retweeted_authors_retweets))
    write_txt_output('output/', 'retweeted_authors', results)

    return results

def followers_count(account, retries):
    try:
        user = api.get_user(account)
        return user.followers_count
    except tweepy.TweepError:
        print('TweepError. Something went wrong in followers_count(' + str(account) + '). Retries: ' + str(retries))
        time.sleep(60) #15 seconds
        if(retries <= 3):
            retries += 1
            time.sleep(60)
            followers_count(account)

def get_followers_count(collection, since, until):
    media_accounts = settings.media_accounts

    i = 0
    for account in media_accounts[0]: #Try to match the given collection with any existent collection
        name = unidecode.unidecode(media_accounts[0][i])
        if(collection == "tweets_" + name.replace(' ', '_')):
            return followers_count(media_accounts[1][i], 0)
        i += 1

    temp = collection.split('_')
    if(temp[0] == 'tweets' or temp[len(temp) - 1] == 'statuses'): #Verifies If the given collection does not exist
        return db.count_single_collection(collection, since, until)             #or If It's a collection not related to tweets o
                                                                  #r followers
    aux = collection.split('_followers')[0]
    return followers_count(aux, 0)

def limit_handled(cursor):
    while(True):
        try:
            # pdb.set_trace()
            # import sys; exc_type, exc_value, tb = sys.exc_info()
            # from pprint import pprint; pprint(tb.tb_frame.f_locals)
            yield cursor.next()
            print("Waiting a minute for request \n")
            time.sleep(1*60)

        except tweepy.RateLimitError:
            print("Rate limit reached \n")
            time.sleep(5*60)
            pdb.set_trace()

        except tweepy.TweepError:
            print("TweepError Error \n")

        except StopIteration:
            print("StopIteration \n")
            break

        except Exception:
            print("Generic Error \n")

def request_followers(name, twitter_id):
    nids = 5000  # number of results
    api.followers_ids(name) #That's the name from the csv
    user = api.get_user(twitter_id) #That is the twitter account from csv
    nfollowers = user.followers_count
    nfullpages = nfollowers/nids
    frac, dec = math.modf(nfullpages)

    # print(nfollowers/5000, nfollowers%5000)
    print("==========================")
    print("user: ", user.screen_name)
    print("frac: ", frac, "dec: ", dec)
    print("nfollowers: ", nfollowers)
    print("==========================")
    print("Start retrieve followers \n")

    pages = []
    pages = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, id=name, count=nids).pages(1)
    # last_page = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, id=account[0], count=(frac*nids), page=(dec+1)).pages()

    for page in limit_handled(pages):
        count = 0
        for id in page:
            count = count + 1
            follower = {"id": str(id)}
            db.insert_one(follower, name + "_followers")
        print("Total followers saveds: ", str(count) + " " + str(twitter_id) + " " + str(name))

def download_followers():
    # this line defines which input take
    # data = settings.medias_accounts_toSearch

    print("Downloading followers..")
    accounts = settings.accounts_toSearch
    #dt = settings.accounts_toSearch

    # dt = settings.medias_accounts_toSearch
    # data = np.dstack((dt[1], dt[0]))[0]
    # print(data)

    while (True):
        index = 0
        while(index < len(accounts)):
            request_followers(accounts[0][index], accounts[1][index])
            index += 1

def download_timeline():
    dt = settings.medias_accounts_toSearch
    data = np.dstack((dt[1],dt[0]))[0]

    print("Start retrieve followers \n")
    while True:
        for account in data:
            user = api.get_user(account[1])
            username = user.screen_name
            number_of_tweets = 20  # 200 MAX
            pages = tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, id=account[0], count=number_of_tweets).pages()
            for page in limit_handled(pages):
                # count = 0
                for status in page:
                    # count = count+1
                    # print(count)
                    tweet = {
                        "id": status.id,
                        "text": status.text
                        # "screen_name": status.screen_name,
                        # "location": status.location,
                    }
                    db.insert_one(tweet, str(account[1])+"_statuses")

            # tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=username, count=number_of_tweets, exclude_replies=True)
            # tweets_for_csv = [[username,tweet["id_str"], tweet["created_at"], tweet["text"].encode("utf-8")] for tweet in tweets]


def search(q):
    print("query search is ", q)
    return api.search(q)


def query():
    dt = settings.urls_toSearch
    data = np.dstack((dt[1],dt[0]))[0]

    for url in data:
        data = search("url:"+url[0])
        print("requesting for [ "+url[1].replace(' ', '_')+" ] \n")

        for dt in data:
            # inspect dt for filter retweeted data
            tweet = {
                "id": str(dt.user.id),
                "text": dt.text,
                "created_at": dt.created_at
            }
            db.insert_one(tweet, "tweets_"+url[1].replace(' ', '_'))

        print("Waiting 1m30 secs to make another query request \n")
        time.sleep(1.5*60)


def make_query():
    while True:
        try:
            query()

        except tweepy.RateLimitError:
            print("Rate limit reached \n")
            time.sleep(15*60)

        except tweepy.TweepError:
            print("Erro \n")

        except:
            print("Erro desconhecido. \n")


def loadBackupData():
    db.import_all_followers()
    db.import_all_tweets()
    print("followers collection imported")

def clearFileOutput(pathToFile):
    os.remove(pathToFile)

def saveFileOutput(data):
    path = os.getcwd()
    fl = path + '/src/data/output.csv'
    clearFileOutput(fl)
    with open( fl, 'w+' ) as f:
        for i in data:
            f.write(i["coll1"]+","+i["coll2"]+","+str(i["qtd"])+"\n")

def processDataGraph():
    # loadBackupData()
    jsonData = db.processCollections()
    print(jsonData)
    saveFileOutput(jsonData)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from report import report
  File "/home/gabriel/bot/twee-crawler/src/report/report.py", line 2, in <module>
    from database import db
  File "/home/gabriel/bot/twee-crawler/src/database/db.py", line 8, in <module>
    from graph import graph
  File "/home/gabriel/bot/twee-crawler/src/graph/graph.py", line 6, in <module>
    from twittery import twittery
  File "/home/gabriel/bot/twee-crawler/src/twittery/twittery.py", line 15, in <module>
    db = db.MongoAccess()
AttributeError: module 'database.db' has no attribute 'MongoAccess'
```

Comment: Any other answer? I still have this issue :(

Answer (score 1):

Change the variable name you are assigning to db.MongoAccess(), as I believe it is conflicting with your import of that class.

e.g. dbase = db.MongoAccess()

Comment: Hi, ty for answering!

Comment: I changed the variable name but the problem persists